# Firebase and JavaScript Security Problem?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I create js chat app  with firebase and users create auth but if users login and  open chrome source my .js file and  add this line  users write my database :S

```
    firebase.database().ref("test").set({
        hacked: "hahaha",
         hacked2: "hahaha",
    });
```

And my rules :

```
"rules": {
   ".read": "auth.uid != null",
   ".write": "auth.uid != null
}
```

what can I do ?

Comment: What can you do? Write better rules

Answer (score 1):

The idea with Firebase security rules is that you are on the hook for coming up with rules that allow only the reads and writes that you want.  You need to be able to express those requirements using the language provided.  The first thing to do would be to [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) to find out what rules can do, then implement them to work as you see fit.  Since we on Stack Overflow don't know what your security requirements are, there's nothing we can do to help.  You're going to have to make an attempt on your own, and if that doesn't work, post what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: I 'am new in  js  and I do all write and read firebase operation in js file. You think this is wrong ? I can change all the rules. But I still have to give permission to write in the messages section.This time users can change the js file and write it in the messages section.